# Logstash - field value compare to mean value from metrics filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, metrics

I'm trying to compare to field value (requestTime) from log, and mean value from [Metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-metrics.html#plugins-filters-metrics-timer) filter

`"requestTime"` is "groked" from my log by: `%{INT:requestTime}`

Filter section:

```
metrics {
    timer => [ "requestPage", "%{requestTime}" ] 
    add_tag => "metric"
}
```

Output section:

```
if "metric" in [tags] {
    if [requestTime] > "[requestPage.mean]" {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
}
```

Logstash's output after that is empty - why?

How to correct compare to `"requestTime"` and `"requestPage.mean"` ?

**EDIT**

```
if "metric" in [tags] {
    if [requestTime] > "[requestPage.mean]" {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
}
```

or

```
if "metric" in [tags] {
    if [requestTime] > [requestPage.mean] {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
}
```

Above solutions doesn't work.

Compilation success without errors, but Logstash output is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your configuration:

```
[requestTime] > [requestPage.mean]"
```

You first need to remove the double quote at the end and then rename the second field to `[requestPage][mean]`

So your output configuration should look like:

```
if "metric" in [tags] {
    if [requestTime] > [requestPage][mean] {
        stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer, you need `[requestPage][mean]`and not `[requestPage.mean]`

Comment: I change it but the result is also empty.